# Pass js var into html block being added via appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

I've got this html which i'm injecting into the page when someone clicks a button. The html gets appended again each time the button is clicked using the js below.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div class="grab-me">
    <p>This is fieldset 1</p>
      <input name="foo[]" />
      <input name="bar[]" />
      <input name="oth[]" />
    </div>
 </div>

var count = 1;
  $(function(){
    $('.add-member').live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        count += 1;
        var grab = $('.grab-me')
                .clone()
                .removeClass('grab-me')
                .appendTo('#register');

    });
 });
```

But what i need to do is where it says "This is fieldset 1" i need to increase that number by 1 each time so subsequent appends say This is fieldset 2, This is fieldset 3 etc etc. I can't see how i can pass a variable (my count var) in to the html block when it gets cloned that will replace that number.

Here is a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/tzbgA/

Any help would be great! Thanks!!

Comment: U could use the innerHTML property,give a class to your `p` tag and set the number .

Comment: Consider using a templating or binding system such as jsRender, Handlerbars, or Knockout.

Comment: @harsha But how will that work bearing in mind it needs to repeat so there will be multiple p elements with that class?

Comment: Could you add a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @howderek Yep, that's done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the sentence you want to change class. Then using jQuery selectors change the text inside it.

```
<body>
  <button class="add-member">add more</button>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="grab-me">
    <p class="count">This is fieldset 1</p>
      <input name="foo[]" />
      <input name="bar[]" />
      <input name="oth[]" />
    </div>
 </div>
  <div id="register">
  </div>
</body>
```

---

```
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('.add-member').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);        
        var grab = $('.grab-me')
                .clone()
                .removeClass('grab-me')
                .appendTo('#register')
        .find('p.count').html('This is fieldset '+count);
      count += 1;
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

add span:

```
 <p>This is fieldset <span>1</span></p> 


   var count = 1;
      $(function(){
        $('.add-member').on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
            count += 1;
            var grab = $('.grab-me')
                    .clone()
                    .removeClass('grab-me')
                    .appendTo('#register');
            $('.span').html('count');

        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('.add-member').live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        count += 1;
        var grab = $('.grab-me').clone();
        $(grab p).html('This is fieldset '+count).appendTo('#register');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/tzbgA/2/

Here's a version that uses 8 lines of code:

#### Code (Javascript)

```
var count = 1,
    html = ' <p>This is fieldset #</p><input name="foo[]"/> <input name = "bar[]"/> <input name = "oth[]"/>';
$(function () {
    $('.add-member').live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);
        document.getElementById("register").innerHTML += html.replace("#",++count);
    });
});
```